# Proving that the axioms for addition hold in $R$ -- Associativity. Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Walter Rudin.

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, rational-numbers, associativity

I'm studying the proof for theorem 1.19 from *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin (public online copy [here](https://notendur.hi.is/vae11/%C3%9Eekking/principles_of_mathematical_analysis_walter_rudin.pdf)).

> There exists an ordered field $R$ which has the least-upper-bound property.
>
> Moreover, $R$ contains $Q$ as a subfield.

The lengthy proof for this theorem is contained in the appendix to chapter 1 on page 17.

I am stuck on Step 4:

> If $\alpha \in R$ and $\beta \in R$ we define $\alpha + \beta$ to be the set of all sums $r + s$, where $r \in \alpha$ and $s \in \beta$.
>
> We define $0^*$ to be the set of all negative rational numbers. It is clear that $0^*$ is a cut. *We verify that the axioms for addition (see Definition 1.12) hold in $R$, with $0^*$ playing the role of $0$*.

Specifically, the author does not prove associativity (A3):

> (A3) As above, this follows from the associative law in $Q$.

I don't really understand what the author is saying here; nor am I sure how to demonstrate this myself (I've tried).

Definition 1.12:

> (A3) Addition is associative: $(x + y) + z = x + (y + z)$ for all $x, y, z \in F$.

The entire reason students such as myself buy textbooks is to have these main concepts explained to them, which Rudin has, for whatever reason, decided not to do. I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to fill this gap by proving the associative property.

Comment: Personal remark to your statement about "gaps in textbook": Students have a very different level and same goes for textbooks.And he wrote, that you have just to use the associative law in $Q$. This hint should be sufficient to do it yourself (just by doing it yourself, you can really understand the details. Reading is not sufficient. You will see!). For more details see the answer below by mathcounterexamples.ne

Comment: There is no doubt that Rudin writes in concise manner and often his expositions are not suitable for self study, but here he hasn't done anything wrong. Almost every thing in theorem 1.19 is trivial (in terms of proof and consequences) apart from the proof that  $R$ possesses least upper bound property. You should focus on that. Other properties follow from corresponding properties of rationals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x, y, z \in R$, which are 3 cuts of $Q$, you have to prove that:
$$(x+y)+z = z+(y+z).$$

What is an element of the cut $(x+y)+z$? It is the sum of an element $p + s$ where $p \in x+y$ and $s \in z$. And the element $p$ can be written (by definition of the cut $x+y$) as $q+r$ where $q \in x$ and $r \in y$.

Therefore an element of $(x+y)+z$ is having the form $(q+r) + s$ where $(q,r,s) \in (x,y,z)$. Now you can use the associative property of the addition in $Q$ to say that $(q+r)+s = q+(r+s) \in x+(y+z)$. We have proven that:
$$(x+y)+z \subseteq x+(y+z)$$.

You can prove in a similar way the converse inclusion which brings you to the conclusion.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am confused as to how an element of $(x + y) + z$ has the form $(p + q) + r$? I understood everything up to here, but I don't see how one can say that $(x + y) + z$ has the form $(p + q) + r$?

Comment: You need to understand that $(x+y)+z$ is a **set** of rational numbers. Using the definition of this set, try to write an element of this set using elements of the sets $x,y,z$.

Comment: But $(p + q) + r$ doesn't have any elements from the set $z$?

Comment: @ThePointer: it is best to use different set of letters for elements of $R$ (say Greek) and for elements of $Q$ (say Roman). This avoids the confusion. Thus if $\alpha\in R$ then $\alpha$ is a set of elements from $Q$ and we can write $x\in\alpha$. Using similar kind of symbols gives the confusion about a set and it's elements. In this answer $p, q, r$ are not sets, but elements of sets like $x, y, z$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks for the response. I understand why different notation is used, but I don't understand how $(x + y) + z$ has the form $(p + q) + r$. For instance, the proof says that $s \in z$; but then there is no element of $z$ in $(p + q) + r$? So how can this be the same form as $(x + y) + z$?

Comment: @ThePointer: *The elements* of $(x+y) +z$ have the form $(p+q) +r$ where $p, q, r\in Q$ *via definition of addition* in $R$. Check the definition of addition. Your comment indicates that you are still confused by the notation. $p, q, r$ are not sets but elements of sets $x, y, z$ respectively. Unless you clear that in your mind you will have a hard time.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh That is my point! How can one say that $(x+y) +z$ and $(p+q) +r$ have the same form, when $p \in x + y$, $q \in x$, $r \in y$? After all, we had that $s \in z$. However, in this new form, we have no elements from the set $z$! Is my point of contention not reasonable?

Comment: Should it not be $(x + y) + z = (q + r) + s$?

Comment: @ThePointer: Ok I got your point. That's a typo in the current answer. We have $(q+r) +s\in (x+y) +z$. This is wrongly written as $(p+q) +r$. Such typos can happen and I expect it will be fixed soon.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Great. I've spent the last 2 hours thinking that I'm a complete idiot for thinking that the answer does not make any sense.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @mathcounterexamples.net. I have now accepted your answer. Thank you for the assistance and insight!

Answer (score -1):

As discussed in the comments to mathcounterexamples.net's answer, there seem to be errors?

I think a correct proof is as follows:

We want to show that $(x + y) + z = x + (y + z)$.

Let $p \in x + y$. Then $p = r + s$, where $r \in x, s \in y$.

Let $c \in z$.

$\therefore (x + y) + z = (r + s) + c$

$(r + s) + c = r + (s + c) \in x + (y + z)$

$\therefore (x + y) + z \subset x + (y + z)$